# Why aren't there any officials for me to kill or heralds for me to bribe?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm not super far into Assassin's Creed: Revelations. I've only just finished the mission where

> Ezio disguises himself as a Janissary so he can kill Tarik the Janissary Captain.

Afterwards I was fleeing a whole mess of Janissaries. Eventually I evaded them and became anonymous, but now my Templar Awareness meter is full and red. No problem - I'll just assassinate some officials and bribe some heralds and I'll be good, right?

Except there aren't any showing up on my map - at all, in any area of the city. I have walked by several heralds, but they aren't talking about me (how dare they!), so I can't bribe them.

Is this a glitch? If not, what do I need to do to get the game to let me get my awareness meter down?

I reloaded the game from the save that happened immediately after I escaped the Janissaries - the problem persists.

Comment: Seems like a legitimate question (since you were obviously confused by it).  You could post your solution (reload the game a few times) as an answer.

Comment: I seem to recall staying red for a few missions after this, but then it reset on its own.  I just assumed it was plot related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the exact same problem about not finding any officials or bribable heralds after the mission you mentioned. Starting a side mission (Tulips for Sophia) had no effect. However, exiting the game and restarting it instantly reset my Templar awareness meter.

For those who do not wish to quit the game: Nick Silversides over at [The Average Gamer](http://www.theaveragegamer.com/2011/11/15/10-top-tips-for-assassins-creed-revelations/) lists (tip number 4) that starting a story plot mission will reset your Templar awareness meter.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this was just a glitch, and that the third time is a charm (in my case). I reloaded from the save a second time and still had the problem. But my third reload dropped me right next to the flower pile I'd hidden from the Janissaries in with a perfectly empty Templar awareness meter, ready to begin my next adventure (or run around killing guards for no real reason).

Edit: Or maybe, as Shinrai notes above, it's plot-related somehow, and the way to get rid of it is either to reload a bunch of times or just keep on keepin' on, doin' missions, and eventually it goes away.

Comment: I had the same issue, after that same mission.  I went to go do a bomb tutorial mission, and all the guards were angry, causing me to fail it.  When I restarted the mission, my awareness was reset.  I'm thinking it's a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with me however I found the easier thing to do was to start the Sophia mission, then wait a little and restart the mission! That sorted it out for me!